# Тёмная тема в Фрагмент кода

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Проблема в том, что в Фрагмент кода, в блоке, где показывается результат, нет тёмной темы

Я везде где только возможно использую встроенную тёмную тему, если не предусмотрено, то пользуюсь плагином Dark Reader. Пока не узнал, что в самом SO есть тёмная тема, рользовался им и тут. Плагин сам работает отлично, но он применяет общие стили для всех сайтов, а встроенная тёмная тема обычно бывает более красивой, т.к. создаётся под конкретный сайт

Так вот из-за того что у меня всё на тёмной теме (телефон, сайты, IDE, комп), то каждый раз, когда открываю Фрагмент кода или запускаю чей-то пример (иногда приходится на всю страницу разворачивать) у меня "ослепляются" глаза на пару секунд, пока я не привыкну к этому белому свету. И потому приходится либо самому стили прописывать, а потом удалять перед публикацией либо заставлять плагин Dark Reader включать сайт SO в список сайтов, где надо менять тему

Так вот предлагаю, чтобы у тех, кто выбрал тёмную тему, по умолчанию блок "Результат" не был абсолютно белым, а был например `#777`

Comment: странно. У меня в темной теме код на черном фоне

Comment: @Эникейщик, результат - это не код, а именно результат, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy А, точно. Я и не знал, что у этой штуки особое название есть, думал, речь про код в самом вопросе/ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Блок с результатом показывает результат той вёрстки, которая написана в вопросе. Не надо над ним издеваться и что-то портить - пусть остаётся как есть.

При особом желании можно попытаться включить вот эту штуку:

[image: auto dark mode]

В [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVOyAVaIctI) говорится, что есть ещё вторая настройка, но мой десктопный хром её не показал. В любом случае, я это никогда не использовал, так что не знаю, насколько хорошо работает.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но я в основном сижу с FF и плагин Dark Reader, тоже может насильно показывать блок "Результат" в тёмном оформлении. Но мне очень нравится цветовая схема тёмной темы самого SO, потому бесит постоянно переключаться только из-за одного блока :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, а как потом в этом сниппете разбираться, где что, если все цвета другие? Вот спрашивают, например, почему жёлтый блок стоит не в том месте, а у тебя там жёлтого вообще нет? На jsfiddle пытались сделать тёмный результат, но быстро передумали.

Comment: Так можно же поменять только цвет `body`. Я, конечно, не ручаюсь за всевозможные случаи, но за всё то время, что я здесь отвечаю, меня вполне удовлетворяло менять только цвет самого `body`, ну или через плагин, если не охота было 3 строчки писать. А в большинстве случаях, на цвет вообще не приходилось ориентироваться при ответе или просмотре результата чужого кода. Опять таки, я не буду утверждать, что это всем всегда удобно и полезно. Но можно например рядом с названием блока "Результат" иметь переключатель темы, который по умолчанию имеет то же значение что и в настройках ползователя